# How do I remove the cartridge from my faucet?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

Nut doesn’t seem to want to turn. I have sprayed WD-40 overnight. Should it? Trying to stop drip.

[image]

Comment: After WD-40 does its Water Displacing thing, try a penetrating oil.

Answer (score 2):

the picture is not very clear on this, but it looks like a left handed thread

you are actually tightening it